# split a number and populate N number of fields in react

Tags: reactjs

for example if we take a number 100 and the  user has three fields when user enters a number say 20 in one of the fields the other two fields should populate with the numbers 40 and 40 as 40+40+20 = 100. Unable to think of a logic which would help me solve this.This is just an example, the number of fields can be considered as N where N = 1,2,3,4 etc .

Answer (score 0):

Seems straightforward, so I might be overlooking the point?

So, first we get whatever element the user interacted with. We could use either `onChange`, which will fire everytime the user changes the input, or `onBlur` which fires when the element loses focus, i.e. submits the form or selects the next input. Then we simply get the `event.target.value`, which in your presented case is `20`.

Get the rest of the inputs by either storing a `ref` to their parent and getting said parents `.children`, or by using `document.querySelectorAll(".some-selector")`, iterate over the nodelist, skip any entry with a `.value !== null` and add `100 - 20 / (nodeList.length - 1)` as the `.value` of the remaining entries.

I would probably use the `ref` route.